# What is the cruise altitude of the Beechcraft Model 18?

Tags: aircraft-performance

I'm trying to find the cruise altitude of the Beechcraft Model 18 (S, Super H18 or any variant), or the range of altitude for such aircraft.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum altitude of a Beech 18 is about 20,000 feet (at 20,500 feet), but you can expect most Beech 18s to fly at around 7,000-9,000 feet.

Source: https://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/beech-model-18/#.XpSqwshKiM8

Comment: As I remember, Beech 18s are unpressurized. As such, I doubt you'd often find them in cruise at altitudes requiring the crew and passengers to be sucking oxygen. Are there pressurized variants of the Beech 18?

Comment: @Terry You could technically manually install pressurization, but I don't know if Beech offers it. But there are actually plenty of Beech aircraft used for skydiving, which results in them giving oxygen to the passengers. But, you are partly right, maybe not 18,000.

Comment: @Terry welcome back!

Comment: @aircanada001 pressurization would require a complete structural redesign of at least the fuselage. This would drive recertification of the aircraft, which would be impossible since it doesn't meet modern design standards. If you pushed through all that what you'd end up with would no longer be a Beech 18.

Comment: okay then @pericynthion